# Remove upfront zeros from floating point lower than 1 in Perl

Tags: perl

I would like to normalize the variable from ie. 00000000.1, to 0.1 using Perl

```
my $number = 000000.1;

$number =\~ s/^0+(\.\d+)/0$1/;
```

Is there any other solution to normalize floats lower than 1 by removing upfront zeros than using regex?

When I try to put those kind of numbers into an example function below

```
test(00000000.1, 0000000.025);

sub test {
    my ($a, $b) = @_;
    print $a, "\n";
    print $b, "\n";
    print $a + $b, "\n";

}
```

I get

```
01
021
22
```

which is not what is expected.

Comment: How are those numbers in there in the first place? `00.1` and `0.1` are the same thing unless these are explicitly in a string representation, which here you are not using. If it is a string, converting it to a numerical value will have the effect of collapsing those anyway.

Comment: `perl -e'printf("%g","000.100");'  ` or `sprintf()`

Comment: it is just an issue I encountered while testing random inputs to the function. Now I wonder how such number can be converted directly to regular float ? Maybe without using regex as the argument is not being put as a string.

Comment: In your example, `00000000.1` is an invalid octal (due to fractal), resulting in octal `01` (decimal `1`), and invalid `0000000.025` results in octal `021` (decimal `17`). try `085` or `0000000.085` and you'll get an error. So fix your input.

Comment: "_testing random inputs_" -- but how do you get an input like that, `00.1`, which isn't a string `'00.1'`? Can't get that kind of a thing into a program. (Except for typing it by hand into the program file.) One can of course have strings like those; see answers for how to make those a number (`0.1` etc)

Answer (score 4):

A number with leading zeros is interpreted as octal, e.g. `000000.1` is `01`. I presume you have a string as input, e.g. `my $number = "000000.1"`. With this your regex is:

```
my $number = "000000.1";
$number =~ s/^0+(?=0\.\d+)//;
print $number;
```

Output:

```
0.1
```

Explanation of regex:

- `^0+` -- 1+ `0` digits
- `(?=0\.\d+)` -- positive lookahead for `0.` followed by digits

***Learn more about regex:*** https://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Codev/TWikiPresentation2018x10x14Regex

Comment: Unortunately, I tried this solution and it gives me exactly the same outcome when I pass the arguments as a float. It works of course when the arguments are put as a string. Is there any way to work directly with the floating point number ?

Comment: The problem with your input `00000000.1` and `0000000.025` is that they are invalid. These look like octal numbers because of leading zeros, but octal numbers can't be fractional. So perl strips non-digits, and converts `0000000.025` to octal `025` and decimal `17` - test it. Where do your numbers originate from?

Answer (score 3):

Simplest way, force it to be treated as a number and it will drop the leading zeros since they are meaningless for decimal numbers

```
my $str = '000.1';
...
my $num = 0 + $str;
```

An example,<sup>†</sup> to run from the command-line:

```
perl -wE'$n = shift; $n = 0 + $n; say $n' 000.1
```

Prints `0.1`

Another, more "proper" way is to format that string (`'000.1'` and such) using [sprintf](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf). Then you do need to make a choice about precision, but that is often a good idea anyway

```
my $num = sprintf "%f", $str;    # default precision
```

Or, if you know how many decimal places you want to keep

```
my $num = sprintf "%.3f", $str;
```

---

<sup>†</sup> The example in the question is really invalid. An unquoted string of digits which starts with a zero (`077`, rather than `'077'`) would be treated as an octal number except that the decimal point (in `000.1`) renders that moot as octals can't be fractional; so, Perl being Perl, it is tortured into a number somehow, but possibly yielding unintended values.

I am not sure how one could get an actual input like that.  If `000.1` is read from a file or from the command-line or from `STDIN` ... it will be a string, an equivalent of assigning `'000.1'`

See [*Scalar value constructors* in perldata](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata#Scalar-value-constructors), and for far more detail, [perlnumber](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlnumber).

Comment: _how one could get an actual input like that_  `perl -e'$num= shift; eval("printf(q|%f|, $num)")' 0000.015`  `13.000000`

Comment: @clamp interesting code but i don't understand -- how is that an example of input of unquoted digits like `00.1` ...?  (Btw, originally I had a word "realistically" there, maybe I should've let it stay... :)

Comment: If used inside an eval, program input can appear as numeric literal instead of a string. I was just wondering what caused the original problem.

Comment: @clamp "_If used inside an eval, program input can appear as numeric literal instead of a string._" -- hm, OK; i don't see that...

Comment: @clamp  "_I was just wondering what caused the original problem_" -- my guess is that they just typed that in for testing, not realizing it's bad input; so it's simply a "manual" error. (But now they insist on it.)  However, they may well need to adjust strings with extra zeros so they serve as numbers.  That's surely not unheard of.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, in Perl, leading zeros produce octal numbers; `10` is just a decimal number ten but `010` is equal to decimal eight. So yeah, the numbers should be in quotes for the problem to make any sense.

But the other answers don’t explain why the printed results look funny. Contrary to [Peter Thoeny’s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75303160/remove-upfront-zeros-from-floating-point-lower-than-1-in-perl#comment132879327_75303441) and [zdim’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75305466), there is nothing ‘invalid’ about the numbers. True, octals can’t be floating point, but Perl does *not* strip the `.` to turn `0000000.025` into `025`. What happens is this:

1. Perl reads the run of zeros and recognises it as an octal number.
2. Perl reads the dot and parses it as the concatenation operator.
3. Perl reads `025` and again recognises it as an octal number.
4. Perl coerces the operands to strings, i.e. the decimal value of the numbers in string form; `0000000` is, of course, `'0'` and `025` is `'21'`.
5. Perl concatenates the two strings and returns the result, i.e. `'021'`.

And without error.

(As an exercise, you can check something like `010.025` which, for the same reason, turns into `'821'`.)

This is why `$a` and `$b` are each printed with a leading zero. Also note that, to evaluate `$a + $b`, Perl coerces the strings to numbers, but since leading zeros in strings do not produce octals, `'01' + '021'` is the same as `'1' + '21'`, returning `22`.